# Probable use of Radon Measure

Tags: measure-theory

The problem is:

Suppose $\mu$ is a positive Borel Measure on $\mathbb R^{1}$ which is finite on bounded sets. If $ \forall f,g \in C_{c} ( \mathbb R^{1})$ ; $ \int_{ \mathbb R^{1}} fg d\mu = (\int_{ \mathbb R^{1}}fd\mu )(\int_{ \mathbb R^{1}}gd\mu)$ , then prove that: $\mu$ is Dirac measure.

My thoughts: Firstly I was thinking about what are all the positive Borel Measure on $\mathbb R^{1}$...that's when it seems that may be something about the properties of Radon Measure could be used!.. But still now I am unable to move the very least.So, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** forget about Radon measures. Just consider that
if  $\mu$ is not a multiple of a Dirac measure, then there is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$\mu((-\infty, x))$ and $\mu((x, +\infty))$ are both positive.

Comment: Why you have considered "a multiple of a Dirac Measure" ?? ... I mean $\mu$ is not a Dirac measure would be sufficient. Isn't it?? & also, where the fact that: $\mu$ is finite on bounded set is being used??

Comment: The idea is to prove first that the given equality implies $\mu = c\delta_x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}, c \in [0, \infty]$. After that you can choose $f, g$ such that $f(x) = g(x) = 1$ and you are left with the equality $c = c^2$. At that point you need to rule out $c = \infty$.

Comment: That too. I assumed that by positive measure you meant a non-negative measure that is not identically zero. The zero measure certainly fulfills all other requirements.

Comment: Sorry!! Unfortunately.. I deleted my previous comment! I apologise for it!